# Check if a substring exists in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if a String exists in my array.

My Javascript Code :

```
if(Ressource.includes("Gold") === true )
         {
             alert('Gold is in my arrray');
         }
```

So Ressource is my array and this array contains :

Ressource ["Gold 780","Platin 500"] // I printed it to check if it was true

I don't understand why my test `if(Ressource.includes("Gold") === true` don't work.

Best regards, I hope someone knows what is wrong with this.

Comment: includes mathes the whole string not a part of it

Comment: hi @Adriani6 i already tryied this and it don't work to.

Comment: hello @ashishsingh there is no way to search only a world in my string ?

Comment: a direct method to achieve it , i am not aware. Indirectly, yes , you can refer the answers people have posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`includes` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) checks whether the string `"Gold"` is contained *as an item* in the array, not whether one of the array items contains the substring. You'd want to use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with the [`includes` string method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for that:

```
Ressources.some(res => res.includes("Gold"))
```

Comment: @DorianGrn you mean like finding the string that includes `Gold`? That would be [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `Array#some`.

Comment: @Bergi With your code how can I display the entire contents of the box of my table that contains the word gold.

Comment: @DorianGrn Which table? You seem to have an array of strings.

Comment: @Bergi i want to get the full string « Gold 780 » into a var ( the full sentence ) lf « Gold » exist, you gave me the way to check if the world gold exist but i don’t know how i can do this. I am new to js. And i meant array not table sorry.

Comment: @DorianGrn Like MinusFour suggested, use `item = Ressource.find(res => res.includes("Gold"))` which will return either the first array item that contains "Gold" or `undefined` if the condition is never satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through your array until you find out if your value exist.

```
if (Ressource.some(x => x.includes("Gold") === true)) {
    alert('Gold is in my arrray');
}
```

Comment: With your code how can I display the entire contents of the box of my table that contains the word gold

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and a simple [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). That would return the value of the element holding the search term. As said in most answers [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) works if your search term matches exactly the array element `Gold 780`.

```js
let Ressource = ["Gold 780","Platin 500"] ;
let found = Ressource.find(function(element) {
let re = new RegExp('Gold');
return element.match(re);
});
console.log(found);
// Working example of Array.prototype.includes()
if(Ressource.includes("Gold 780")) {
  console.log('Gold is in my arrray');
}
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veo42qd9/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a number along with Gold in the string in your array. Try using regex like this:

```js
var Ressource = ["Gold 232331","Iron 123"]

if(checkForGold(Ressource) === true ) {
  console.log('Gold is in my array');
} else {
  console.log('Gold is not in my array');
}

function checkForGold(arr) {
   var regex = /Gold\s(\d+)/;
   return arr.some(x=>{if(x.match(regex))return true});
}
```

The MDN docs have a [excellent guide to regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Try this instead.